# Comparator based on a configurable order

Tags: java

Is there a way to write custom comparator, following this example:

There are at most 10 items coming in at a random order
i.e.

```
first item:  item_one
second:      second_one
third:       third_one
```

I want result them to be sorted like : `second_one`, `third_one`, `first_one`. I'd like to pull this order from configuration file, sort of like template for sorting.

Am I using the wrong data structure, does anyone have experience with this?

Comment: I don't see what ordering this is.  Can you elaborate on what you mean by the ordering?

Comment: @templatetypedef there is no logical explanation for this sorting flow, thats why I'd like to create comparator which uses some kind of template so it knows how to sort.

Comment: If it has an order, it is not a `Set` but a `List`. And you can use `Comparator`s on `List`s as you wish.

Comment: I guess I don't understand your question, then.  What does sorted order mean for these objects?  The sorted ordering you gave above doesn't look sorted at all.

Comment: @London: its not clear even after your reply. Define the "order" on the elements. i.e. given two elements x and y, how do you decide whether x<y is true or not?

Comment: @Bombe, which `List` takes a `Comparator`? Quite the opposite, if you need to provide a `Comparator`, use a `TreeSet` which is a `Set`.

Comment: @templatetypedef if it did have some logic to it, I'd simply write a method in which I'd determine some logic to decide in which order to sort, however this may not be sorting, but I want the order to be decided based on anything I provide as a template. @MAK that is the deal, I can't think of algorithm/logic to determine how this should be sorted, I just want to sort it based on what I provide in my template.

Comment: What do you mean by "template?". Are you given the ordering explicitly in another location and then want to keep everything sorted by the order from that template?

Comment: @Steve, `Collections.sort()` takes a `List` and a `Comparator`.

Comment: @Bombe I was thinking the same, maybe I'm using a wrong data structure, but than again I don't know how to do it using a list as well at this time

Comment: @templatetypedef yes that is exactly what I mean

Comment: @London: Can you give your specific case? Maybe someone here can see a logical way to sort your data.

Comment: @Jeremy Heiler that is the case I provided in the question .. you might think middle one +1 then middle one -1 .. but it gets weird later on .. no logic what so ever

Comment: @London ... then if you know the indexes, why can't you just keep a list of those indexes in the order you want and iterate over it, using each index to access that position in the collection.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Sure. Here is an "`OrderedComparator`" that compares elements according to a predefined order:

```
class OrderedComparator implements Comparator<String> {

    List<String> predefinedOrder;

    public OrderedComparator(String[] predefinedOrder) {
        this.predefinedOrder = Arrays.asList(predefinedOrder);
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        return predefinedOrder.indexOf(o1) - predefinedOrder.indexOf(o2);
    }

}
```

And here is some test code. (I used a `List` instead of a `Set` since it 1) seem more natural when talking about the order of the elements and 2) better illustrate what happens with duplicate elements upon sorting using this comparator.)

```
class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Order (could be read from config file)
        String[] order = { "lorem", "ipsum", "dolor", "sit" };


        List<String> someList = new ArrayList<String>();

        // Insert elements in random order.
        someList.add("sit");
        someList.add("ipsum");
        someList.add("sit");
        someList.add("lorem");
        someList.add("dolor");
        someList.add("lorem");
        someList.add("ipsum");
        someList.add("lorem");


        System.out.println(someList);

        Collections.sort(someList, new OrderedComparator(order));

        System.out.println(someList);
    }

}
```

**Output:**

```
[sit, ipsum, sit, lorem, dolor, lorem, ipsum, lorem]
[lorem, lorem, lorem, ipsum, ipsum, dolor, sit, sit]
```

Comment: I'd suggest changing the List to a Map from elements to their positions for efficiency reasons, but this is exactly what I was about to write. :-)

Comment: the OP wanted a Set not a List

Comment: I motivated why I chose a List instead of a Set in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at TreeSet (http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html). You can provide a custom Comparator in a constructor. This Comparator will take into account your config. file . The logic of the comparator will not be pretty though since you want arbitrary order. You will most probably end up enumerating all possible comparisons.

Comment: can you give an example please, I don't know what you mean.

Comment: So your text file has a row for every pair, let's say the values are ABCD, and lets say that the order is A > B > C > D

A B
A C
A D
B C
B D
C D
  
every line means that the first value is greater then the second value. You will read the file into your comparator and create a table which you will consult every time you need to do compare(). For example you can have a hashmap with keys like "AB", "BD" end so on and values -1 or 1 to indicate if the first part of the key is less then the second. 

wish I knew how to add line breaks here

Comment: But for a small set of values, aioobe's solution is much better, You can still use the comparator he provided in a tree set

Answer (score 1):

A set stores unordered elements. If you want to compare and sort, you should probably go with a list. Here's a quick snippet for you:

```
List<X> sorted = new ArrayList<X>(myset);
Collections.sort(sorted, new Comparator<X>() {
    public int compare(X o1, X o2) {
        if (/* o1 < o2 */) {
            return -1;
        } else if (/* o1 > o2 */) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
});
```

Now you've got `sorted`, which has all the same elements of `myset`, which was unordered by virtue of being a set.

You can also look at `TreeSet`, which orders its elements, but it's generally not a good idea to rely on a set being ordered.

Comment: >> generally not a good idea to rely on a set being ordered.   why do you say that?

Comment: Because it's a set, not a list. Maybe it's just my math background, but I don't like it.

Comment: -1 It's not a good idea to rely on a generic set being ordered but the whole point of the SortedSet interface(which TreeSet extends) is to guarentee an ordering

Comment: @gcooney I didn't say you shouldn't rely on a `SortedSet` being sorted. I said that you shouldn't rely on a `Set` being sorted, and that I do not personally like the idea of a sorted set.

Comment: @Jonathon Considering the fact that the OP can choose the type of Set he wants to use, I find it misleading to use the unreliable ordering of generic Sets as an argument against using any set.

Comment: @Jonathon, so if you wanted a sorted collection that had no duplicates, you still recommend Lists? That's really inefficient especially as the collection gets large.

Comment: Perhaps my opinion comes from never having needed a sorted collection without duplicates. `TreeSet` does seem to solve the problem in this case, so it probably is the correct tool.

Answer (score 0):

Use Guava's com.google.common.collect.Ordering:

```
Ordering.explicit(second_one, third_one, first_one);
```